# Can a USB socket draw more than 5 V?

Tags: usb, over-voltage-protection

As a complete newbie in electronics world, I need some advice.

My circuit has a female USB Type A socket for the source and my load is a 5 W 10ohm cement resistor used for heating. As long as the source is 5 V, rated load on my resistor is 50% and is enough for its purpose.

My questions are:

- For the consumer side, should I worry about overvoltage i.e. is there any possibility this device will receive more than ~5 V?
- What should I do for this if it can?

Can you give additional suggestions? I am thinking of using a PTC thermistor, in case the cement material wears out in time and produces more heat.

Comment: Voltage isn't "drawn", current is.

Comment: _"My circuit has a female usb type a socket for the source"_ - do you mean your circuit plugs into a type A socket for power? What exactly is the power source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A USB host port always supplies 5V when the device is first plugged in.

If the host port and the device both support the USB power deliver specification, then the device can request that the host supply another voltage (up to 20V max).  If either the host or the device don't support the power delivery specification, then the host will supply only 5V.

Power delivery is a relatively newer feature, and in my experience the majority of host USB ports don't yet support the power deliver specification and therefore can only supply 5V.

In any case, if you designed your device for 5V operation, and you aren't specifically requesting that the host give you more than 5V, then it should be fine to assume you will only get 5V.

Comment: There is also Qualcomm's quickcharge, and whatever it was that, i think it was Huawei did? which work similarly.

Comment: USB hosts always supply 5 V at plug-in but at a reduced current (I seem to recall 100 mA for USB 2.x, 500 mA for USB 3.x). That may not be enough for all of the device operations. Device configuration lets it request a higher current.